# Display Content on the basis of child terms of selected taxonomy term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have created A vocabulary like

```
Category
-category1
--category1.1
---category 1.1.1
--category1.2
---category1.2.1
-category2
--category2.1
--category2.2
```

trying to display content having category 1.1 and category 1.2 node view where term is category 1
 But its also displaying the child node of category 1.1 i.e category 1.1.1 and child 1.2 i.e category 1.2.1.